# Is this a legitimate way to compute a contour integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

I wish to calculate $$\int_{\Gamma}\cos(z)\sin(z)~\text{d}z$$ where $\Gamma$ is the line segment given by $\gamma(t)=\pi t+(1-t)i$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$.

Here is what I did:

We have that $$\int \cos(z)\sin(z)~\text{d}z= \frac{\sin^2(z)}{2}$$ Also

$\gamma(0)=i$ and $\gamma(1)=\pi$  so $$\int_{\Gamma}\cos(z)\sin(z)~\text{d}z = \frac{\sin^2(\pi)}{2}-\frac{\sin^2(i)}{2}=-\color{blue}{\frac{\sin^2(i)}{2}}$$

I have a feeling this is how you can calculate these types of line integrals in an analogous way to computing line integrals of conservative vector fields.

Would anyone be able to tell me what conditions are needed on $\Gamma$ and on $f(z)$ to allow one to do this, I would assume that $f(z)$ has to be holomorphic on $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ needs to be a simple closed contour but I'm not entirely sure.

Also what is this theorem called so I can do some more reading on it later.

Thank you!

Comment: use $ signs across math functions

Comment: ? I used $ signs throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The theorem you are talking about is the following:

> If $\Omega$ is a domain in $\Bbb C$, $f: \Omega \to \Bbb C$ has a primitive $F$ on $\Omega$ and $\Gamma: [a,b] \to \Omega$ is a path in $\Omega$, then: $\int_{\Gamma} f = F(\Gamma(b)) - F(\Gamma(a))$

In your case, the function has a primitive on $\Bbb C$ (which is a domain), and of course the segment is a path in $\Bbb C$, so the theorem applies.

Answer (score 1):

About the path $\Gamma$, at least you need it to be rectifiable (not closed neither simple) so that $\int_\Gamma|dz|=length(\Gamma)<+\infty$. With this condition it is enough to have $f$ holomorphic in the range of $\Gamma$ (in an open set containing it). But how much can be relaxed this conditions on $f$?. Well, you cannot ask less that what Ahmed said. This is because given $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$, $\Omega$ domain, if you identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $z=x+iy\leftrightarrow (x,y)$, then you might view $f$ as a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and for vector fields we have that path-independence of a line integral is equivalent to the vector field being conservative.

To see $\int_\Gamma f(z)dz$ as a line integral write $f$ separating real and imaginary parts $f=u+iv$. Then you have that
$$
\int_\Gamma f(z)dz=\int_\Gamma [u(x,y)+iv(x,y)][dx+idy]=
$$
$$
=\int_\Gamma[u(x,y)dx-v(x,y)dy]+i\int_\Gamma[v(x,y)dx+u(x,y)dy].
$$